# What is the word that describes a demanding look?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, verbs, idioms

Is there an idiom or a single verb for a patronizing stare or a demanding look? As if someone can speak with his looks and says something like "No!", "Stop!", "Do it now!" and makes people obey no matter how much they don't want to.

Comment: Yes, the word that describes a demanding look is *demanding*.

Comment: It's not a verb, but your description makes me want to say 'Ocular hack'.

Answer (score 4):

We can say *an imperious look*.

Comment: Merriam-Webster defines *imperious* as *having or showing the proud and unpleasant attitude of someone who gives orders and expects other people to obey them*. That comes pretty close, I think, to the OP's "patronizing stare or a demanding look".

Comment: The OP mentions "make people obey no matter how much they don't want to".  The Collins dictionary cites the following as synonyms for "imperious": *domineering, dictatorial, bossy, haughty, lordly, commanding, arrogant, authoritative, autocratic, overbearing, tyrannical, magisterial, despotic, high-handed, overweening, tyrannous*

Answer (score 1):

An old saying for a *demanding* look is, to look at someone with *"daggers in your eyes."*

If you are being patronizing, you would give someone a *"withering look"*. (To cause them to "shrivel up")(US)

Comment: But "looking daggers" has nothing to do with making people do things. They realise you want to get medieval on their asses, that's all. "Withering look" likewise, no compulsion or geas implied, they just know you despise them or strongly disapprove of what they just said/did.

Comment: @David Pugh - Really? Are you married? Have kids? I find "dagger looks" quite effective for getting feet wiped, wet towels off the floor, 'put back that cookie jar, this instant!", etc.

Comment: Then I won't marry you!

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, it is often referred to as a "Paddington stare".

This refers to the character Paddington Bear who found fame in the books of Michael Bond, which have been adapted for TV and movie.

> “Paddington had a very persistent stare when he cared to use it. It
>   was a very powerful stare. One which his Aunt Lucy had taught him and
>   which he kept for special occasions.”

Examples of former Prime Minister Gordon Brown using the technique may be found [here](http://www.anorak.co.uk/226128/politicians/gordon-brown-fixes-adam-boulton-with-a-paddington-bear-stare.html/) with an article entitled "Gordon Brown Fixes Adam Boulton With A Paddington Bear Stare"

Answer (score 0):

*a [patronizing, etc] **frown, scowl, glower, lower, gloom***

Water from the best fount:-)

> [**A Dictionary of Discriminated Synonyms with Antonyms and Analogous and
>   Contrasted Words Merriam-Webster**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA363&dq=scowl%20synonym&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6V06VZWVNKvLsASox4CgCg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=scowl%20synonym&f=false), Inc - 1984
>
> *Frown, scowl, glower, lower, gloom* are comparable when they mean to
>   put on a dark or malignant countenance or aspect.

[read the entire discrimination]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an "importunate" look..?

Comment: Merriam Webster: _Importunate_: 1.  troublesomely urgent :  overly persistent in request or demand.